# SSH to Google Compute instance using NodeJS, without gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a SSH tunnel into a compute instance, from an environment that doesn't have `gcloud` installed (App Engine Standard NodeJS Environment).

What are the steps needed to do that? How does `gcloud compute ssh` command does it? Is there a NodeJS library that already does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the package [gcloud-ssh-tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcloud-ssh-tunnel) that does the necessary steps:

1. Create a private/public key using [sshpk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sshpk)
2. Imports the public key using the [OS Login API](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/os-login/0.3.x/v1beta.OsLoginServiceClient#importSshPublicKey)
3. SSH using [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) (and specifically create a tunnel, because this was the use case I needed - see the `Why?` section in the package)
4. Delete the public key using the [OS Login API](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/os-login/0.3.x/v1beta.OsLoginServiceClient#deleteSshPublicKey) (to not overflow the account or leave security access)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ssh2](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) to do that in nodejs.

Comment: That's not all `gcloud compute ssh` does, it also creates and adds a private/public key using OS login

Answer (score 1):

"gcloud compute ssh" generates persistent SSH keys for the user. The public key is stored in project or instance SSH keys metadata, and the Guest Environment creates the necessary local user and places ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in its home directory.
You can manually add your public key to the instance, and then connect to it via ssh using a node ssh library[1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).
Or you can set a startup script for the instance when you are creating it[2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).
As Cloud Ace pointed out, you can use the ssh2 module[3](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) for node.js compatibility.

---

Comment: It's actually using something called OS Login - it stores the public key for the specific service account and *not* the specific VM instance metadata. I was hoping there was something that does it all for me (like `gcloud compute ssh` CLI command)

Comment: OS Login is actually considered, following the official documention, as an advance method to connect to the VM Instance. And not related to how "gcloud compute ssh" works. But as you commented, this method still needs the gcloud library to connect to the instance. The official documentation details how these methods work, which are the only available ones to connect to a GCP VM Instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#provide-key

Answer (score 1):

In order to SSH into a GCP instance you have to:

1. Enable [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin)
2. Create a service account and assign it "Compute OS Admin Login" role.
3. Create SSH key and import it into the service account.
4. Use that SSH key and POSIX username.

The first 2 steps already link to the documentation.

Create SSH key:

```js
import {
  generatePrivateKey,
} from 'sshpk';

const keyPair = generatePrivateKey('ecdsa');

const privateKey = keyPair.toString();
const publicKey = keyPair.toPublic().toString();
```

Import key:

```js
const osLoginServiceClient = new OsLoginServiceClient({
  credentials: googleCredentials,
});

const [result] = await osLoginServiceClient.importSshPublicKey({
  parent: osLoginServiceClient.userPath(googleCredentials.client_email),
  sshPublicKey: {
    expirationTimeUsec: ((Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1_000) * 1_000).toString(),
    key: publicKey,
  },
});
```

SSH using the key:

```js
const ssh = new NodeSSH();

await ssh.connect({
  host,
  privateKey,
  username: loginProfile.posixAccounts[0].username,
});
```

In this example, I am using [`node-ssh`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh) but you can use anything.

The only other catch is that you need to figure out the public host. Implementation for that looks like this:

```js
const findFirstPublicIp = async (
  googleCredentials: GoogleCredentials,
  googleZone: string,
  googleProjectId: string,
  instanceName: string,
) => {
  const instancesClient = new InstancesClient({
    credentials: googleCredentials,
  });

  const instances = await instancesClient.get({
    instance: instanceName,
    project: googleProjectId,
    zone: googleZone,
  });

  for (const instance of instances) {
    if (!instance || !('networkInterfaces' in instance) || !instance.networkInterfaces) {
      throw new Error('Unexpected result.');
    }

    for (const networkInterface of instance.networkInterfaces) {
      if (!networkInterface || !('accessConfigs' in networkInterface) || !networkInterface.accessConfigs) {
        throw new Error('Unexpected result.');
      }

      for (const accessConfig of networkInterface.accessConfigs) {
        if (accessConfig.natIP) {
          return accessConfig.natIP;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  throw new Error('Could not locate public instance IP address.');
};
```

Finally, to clean up, you have to call `deleteSshPublicKey` with the name of the key that you've imported:

```js
const fingerprint = crypto
  .createHash('sha256')
  .update(publicKey)
  .digest('hex');

const sshPublicKey = loginProfile.sshPublicKeys?.[fingerprint];

if (!sshPublicKey) {
  throw new Error('Could not locate SSH public key with a matching fingerprint.');
}

const ssh = new NodeSSH();

await ssh.connect({
  host,
  privateKey,
  username: loginProfile.posixAccounts[0].username,
});

await osLoginServiceClient.deleteSshPublicKey({
  name: sshPublicKey.name,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'd need to reserve & assign a [static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) to begin with (unless trying to SSH from within the same network). And a firewall rule needs to be defined for port `tcp/22`, which then can be applied as a "label" to the network interface, which has that external IP assigned.

The other way around works with `gcloud app instances ssh`:

> SSH into the VM of an App Engine Flexible instance

which might be less effort & cost to setup, because a GCP VM usually has `gcloud` installed.

Comment: I was actually looking to SSH into a normal VM, not into a App Engine managed VM