# How to ssh to a gcloud virtual machine through node.js client library

Tags: node.js, ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, client-library

I have a Google Cloud VM named `cloudvm` and a Node.js script to contact that virtual machine. I want to take a shell and execute

```
echo "this is fun" > a.txt
```

command using a ssh client in Node.js. I have tried `node-ssh` with userid,password and private key and following error occurs;

```
Message: All configured authentication methods failed
```

I have used

```
   const {NodeSSH} = require('node-ssh')

const ssh = new NodeSSH()

ssh.connect({
  host: 'localhost',
  username: 'steel',
  privateKey: '/home/steel/.ssh/id_rsa'
})
```

My final goal is to pass a value to a file inside the Google Cloud VM using Node.js environment. Any ideas?

Comment: Google Cloud by default does not enable **username/password** authentication. By default only SSH keypairs are enabled. When posting a question, show your code and the error/problem your code has after you have put some debugging effort into your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH to Google Compute instance using NodeJS, without gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321081/ssh-to-google-compute-instance-using-nodejs-without-gcloud)

Comment: @JohnHanley already put code and error . Thanks, i figured it early .You should create os user and password to access it through cloud shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After creating**

> OS user and password

**in google compute engine  you can connect it via node-ssh library in node JS .**

```
const { NodeSSH } = require("node-ssh");
const ssh = new NodeSSH();
var session = await ssh.connect({
      host: "xxx.xxx.x.xx",
      username: "xxxxxx",
      password: "xxxx",
    });
    var cmde = 'your/command to execute';
    var ot = await session.execCommand(cmde);
```